# Поочередно менять цвет цифр

Tags: c#, wpf, форматирование

У меня по нажатию кнопки должно менять цвет каждой цифры в `Label`. До этого делал 4 `Label` и по очереди менял их цвет но это очень крупно получается. Можно ли в моей ситуации как-ни-будь попроще или это единственный вариант? 
Вот как делал раньше. Тут каждый `Label` это своя цифра, а я бы хотел в один `Label` все 4 цифры. Они разделены пробелом:

```
Label[] labels = {label1,label2,label3,label4};
int labelsCounter = 0;
private void NextApproach_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    labels[labelsCounter].Foreground = Brushes.LightCoral;
    labelsCounter++;
    if (labelsCounter == labels.Length)
    {
        //SomeCode
    }
}
```

Comment: Какие цифры? Для чего? Нельзя цвет во вьюмодель добавить и прибиндить лейблы на него? Тогда просто меняете цвет во воьюмодели и вуаля

Comment: Если у вас цифры, это свой отдельный объект и их кол-во меняется, то создайте коллекцию, которая будет содержать VM данного объекта (имя, цвет, действие и др) и выводите их как коллекцию через тот же `ItemsControl` или его аналог... Если же у вас статичные цифры, то сделайте `TextBlock`, который будет содержать внутри `Run` со своим текстом и цветом.

Comment: у меня цифр всегда 4, но он могут быть в диапазоне от 0 до 100. Если можно показать пример кода.

Comment: Тогда самый [простой вариант](https://hastebin.com/tazameniru.xml)...

Comment: а изменение значения можно запретить?

Comment: Так это же тот же Lable по сути, простой вывод текста на экран. Привязанные данные - это у вас будут некие свойства с которыми сами уже в праве что угодно делать...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А как редактировать текст?

Comment: Как и обычный Lable, либо дайте имя и меняйте, либо реализуйте привязку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот как один из вариантов с привязками и MVVM*:

1. Создадим базовый класс для реализации `INotifyPropertyChanged`

   ```
   public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

       protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
       {
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Создадим VM нашего числа, которая будет содержать в себе само число, цвет и простой метод для сброса цвета на стандартное:

   ```
   public class Number : BaseViewModel
   {
       public Number(int numb)
       {
           Numb = numb;
           Color = Brushes.Black;
       }

       private int numb;
       private Brush color;

       public int Numb
       {
           get => numb;
           set
           {
               numb = value;
               OnPropertyChanged();
           }
       }

       public Brush Color
       {
           get => color;
           set
           {
               color = value;
               OnPropertyChanged();
           }
       }

       public void ClearColor() => Color = Brushes.Black;
   }
   ```
3. Далее нам нужна сама коллекция, которую мы заполним нашими цифрами:

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<Number> Numbers { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Number>
   {
       new Number(1),
       new Number(2),
       new Number(3),
       new Number(4)
   };
   ```
4. Я лично размещаю эту коллекцию прям в `MainWindow` (но лучше все разделять на отдельные VM слои) и по этому как `DataContext` я укажу окно:

   ```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = this;
   }
   ```
5. Далее нам нужен функционал кнопки. Для изменения значений по очереди, нам понадобится какой нибудь счетчик, простое число. Также для удобства (что бы не вычислять позже) мы вынесем отдельно еще и предыдущее, "покрашенное" нами число:

   ```
   private int current;
   private Number prev;
   ```
6. Теперь код самого действия:

   - Вычисляем необходимую нам цифру. Я лично сделаю это с помощью LINQ, а именно метода `Skip()` (который пропустит определенное число объектов) и `FirstOrDefault()` (который возьмет первый, подходящий нам элемент).
   - Если сохраненная нами предыдущая цифра не равна `null`, то выполняем сброс цвета.
   - Если наша следующая цифра не равна `null` (то есть найдена), меняем ей цвет и сохраняем ее для будущего изменения.
   - Ну и сам счетчик, если он меньше объектов в нашей коллекции, то прибавляем, иначе сбрасываем на ноль.

Код всего `MainWindow` в итоге будет следующим:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Number> Numbers { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Number>
    {
        new Number(1),
        new Number(2),
        new Number(3),
        new Number(4)
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private int current;
    private Number prev;

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var next = Numbers.Skip(current).FirstOrDefault();

        prev?.ClearColor();

        if (next != null)
        {
            next.Color = Brushes.Red;
            prev = next;
        }

        current = current < Numbers.Count-1 ? current + 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

7. Все, осталось сделать нам XAML разметку. Она до безобразия проста:

   - `StackPanel`, которая позволяет нам разместить рядом контролы. В нее помещаем кнопку и `ItemsControl`.
   - `ItemsControl` - простейший вывод нашей коллекции так, как нам захочется. С помощью `ItemsPanel` задаем отображение элементов построчно, а с помощью `ItemTemplate` мы задаем вид каждого элемента.

В итоге получаем следующее:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Numb}" Foreground="{Binding Color}" FontSize="25"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <Button Content="Сменить" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Запускаем и любуемся результатом:

[image: Result]

**Я не буду реализовывать тут команды и отдельный VM для основной логики. Так что это почти правильный MVVM. В реальном проекте стоит задуматься над реализацией команд, а не использовать `Click`!*

Answer (score 1):

Просто немного поправлю код, чтобы не переживать за значение `labelsCounter`

```
Label[] labels = {label1,label2,label3,label4};
int labelsCounter = 0;

private void NextApproach_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    labels[labelsCounter].Foreground = Brushes.LightCoral;
    labelsCounter = (labelsCounter+1) % labels.length;        
}
```

Теперь можно нажимать кнопку сколько хочешь, `labelsCounter` никогда не выйдет за рамки массива `labels`;